# Removing a border line in Silverlight Border control (kind of like border-style-bottom:none in css)?

Tags: silverlight, border

I'd like the ability to have something that looks like a border but I don't 
want the bottom to show. in CSS I could accomplish this by going border-style-bottom:none
I'm wondering if Silverlight has a similar functionality for the Border control.

If not, I'm wondering what other control I can use to accomplish this? thanks

Answer (score 10):

It works like this:-

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2,2,2,0">
...
</Border>
```

Another form just takes two numbers "lr,tb" which specifies the thickness of the left and right of the border then the top and bottom of the border.

Comment: @Shnitzel: Think nothing of it :P